# Is it possible to bound recurrence functions for primes?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers

Would it be possible to bound this function for primes in terms of the maximum difference between the images of the function and their closest primes (for instance, the fifth term is 33 and has difference of two in terms of its closest prime, 31):

$2 g(n-1) = g(n)+1$

I have found that the images are main,y bounded by a difference of four 4 or 2 for the closest primes, however certain images can be bound by 30 as I have heuristicly found. But, my question is, would it be possible, perhaps using the P.N.T. and other number theoretical or group theoretical tools,to find a bound for the primes for each image?

Comment: " this function for primes " What function for primes? Please rephrase your question, it's unclear.

Comment: The recurrence function is the one I have written, 
2 g(n-1) = g(n)+1.   What I have meant to say is if it is possible to find the gap between the closest prime to any image of the function. For example, 33 is the fifth term and has a gap of two between the closest prime.

Comment: Without setting $g(1)$, you still don't have a function.

Comment: maybe it is a needlessly complicated and obfuscated way to describe the sequence $2^n+1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the smallest (absolute) distance from $x$ to some positive prime number, so $f(1)=2-1=1,\ f(2)=2-2=0,\ f(10)=11-10=1,$ etc. Then the question is asking for $f(g(n))$ where $g(n)=2^n+1.$

For $x\ge58837$ there is a prime between $x$ and $x(1+\frac{1.188}{\log^3x})$.[1] So for $n>15$ we have
$$
f(g(n))<\frac{1.188(2^n+1)}{\log^3(2^n+1)}.
$$
You can get this to about
$$
f(g(n))\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{1.784\cdot2^n}{n^3}.
$$
with more careful analysis (which I have not performed).

[1] Christian Axler, New bounds for the prime counting function π(x), 2014. http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1780